# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because the return value of "Utils.DriverUtils.getDriver()" is null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting some error in test ng but unable to understand why !

This is my file for driver utils :

```
package Utils;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DriverUtils {
    static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void createDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Rohit Nagar\\eclipse-workspace\\Hexaware_OrangeHRM\\src\\test\\resources\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/login");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
    }
    
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if(driver==null) {
            createDriver();
        }
        
        return driver;
    }
    
}
```

This is code for BasePage:

```
package POM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Utils.DriverUtils;

public class BasePage {
    WebDriver driver;
    BasePage(){
        driver = DriverUtils.getDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Code for Login Page:

```
package POM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class LoginPages extends BasePage {
    //Declaration
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id = 'Email']")
    private WebElement txtUser;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id = 'Password']")
    private WebElement txtPassword;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@class= 'button-1 login-button']")
    private WebElement buttonLogin;
    
    public void enterUsername(String str) {
        txtUser.sendKeys(str);
    }
    
    public void enterPassword(String str) {
        txtPassword.sendKeys(str);
    }
    
    public void loginClick() {
        buttonLogin.click();
    }
}
```

And this is my testlogin PAge:

```
package Test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import POM.LoginPages;
import Utils.DriverUtils;

public class LoginTestOne {
    @Test
    public void verifyLogin() throws InterruptedException {
        DriverUtils.getDriver().get("https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/login");
        
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        LoginPages lp = new LoginPages();
        
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        
        lp.enterUsername("");
        
        lp.enterPassword("");
        lp.loginClick();
        
    }
}
```

**This is what error I am getting in eclipse :**

```
*FAILED: Test.LoginTestOne.verifyLogin
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because the return value of "Utils.DriverUtils.getDriver()" is null
    at Test.LoginTestOne.verifyLogin(LoginTestOne.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a simple mistake in `DriverUtil`.

```
public class DriverUtils {
    static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void createDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "...");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   // MISTAKE
        ...
    }
    
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            createDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `createDriver` has declared a local `driver` variable, so it is not updating the `static WebDriver driver` field.

Thus ... the `getDriver()` method is ALWAYS going to return `null`.

---

There are other flaws in your code:

- You have embedded the absolute path to a chromedriver within you home directory ... into your code.  That means that the tests will fail if anyone else tries to run them.
- This code is not thread-safe.  It probably doesn't matter in this context, but if you were ever to run the tests in parallel, some threads would share the `WebDriver` instance, and others wouldn't.
- If tests share a `WebDriver`  instance, they could interfere with each other.  Indeed, if the tests are running simultaneously, it could be rather ... bad.

Comment: Yes I got it , it was just a silly mistake !!